# librería para resolver ecuaciones diferenciales ordinarias

Tags: php, python, matemáticas

Alguien sabe de alguna librería que se pueda usar con php, que me permita resolver ecuaciones diferenciales ordinarias?
En mi trabajo hay un programa de escritorio hecho en Python que hace este proceso, pero desean que ahora sea web... la pregunta de ustedes será ¿porque no lo haces con Django?, pasa que no nunca revisé programación con Python, menos con Django (que sería el framework para web)... se programar con PHP.
El trabajo lo requieren en un tiempo corto, así que no se que es mejor y más rápido... si conseguir la librería que me permita hacer estos cálculos o aprender a programar con Python y usar Django para su versión web.

Gracias por sus aportes

Comment: Se me ocurre que si es un script .py podrias ejecutarlo a través de las funciones exec o shell_exec para obtener la salida del script y presentarla en pantalla con php.

Comment: O puedes crear un microservicio con [tag:flask] que solo llamarás para hacer el cálculo y devolver el resultado y que se integre con el resto del PHP que ya tengas.

Answer (score 0):

@DanielZam, Si te gusta aprender otros lenguajes, Python tiene una curva de aprendizaje que seguramente se adapta a tu calendario de desarrollo, ademas, existen tutoriales, librerias y scripts que te pueden ayudar con lo que necesitas.

En el caso que te decantes por Python, tienes este [enlace](http://apmonitor.com/che263/index.php/Main/PythonDynamicSim) (en inglés) en el que explican como resolver ecuaciones diferenciales con Python (usando numpy). En el caso de PHP tienes ayuda y aportaciones en la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.math.php#43073) oficial sobre como puedes hacerlo con PHP. Espero que te sea de ayuda.